# Height of potential barrier

Tags: electrochemistry, reference-request, silver

Could anyone please help to find the height of the potential barrier between silver and copper or $\ce{Ag-Cu}$. I am working on a piezo-resistive sensor based on copper fabric and silver electrodes. I was wondering if I can validate my experimental results with the model given by Zhang, X.-W., et al. <sup>[1]</sup>

I am not a chemistry expert and have a little knowledge on the height of the potential barrier. It would be highly appreciated if anyone could help me with providing the value for the height of the requested potential barrier.

[1] Zhang, X.-W., et al., Time dependence of piezoresistance for the conductor-filled polymer composites. Journal of Polymer Science Part B: Polymer Physics, 2000. 38(21): p. 2739-2749.